# How to override django.contrib.gis

Tags: python, django, admin, geodjango

I modified some code in ../contrib/gis/admin/options.py
and also the openlayers.js file in ../contrib/gis/templates/admin.

It works fine like this but I can't let them that way because they will be replaced in case of django update!
So I want a copy of those files in my project and leave the original ones in /django/contrib...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you need to change?

Comment: @Thomas: I need to add new default settings for my second wms layer. Something like:`wms2_url = 'http://X.X.X.X:8080/geoserver/wms'
    wms2_layer = 'layer_name_on_server'
    wms2_name = 'name_WMS'` I am now thinking about creating a subclass to the GeoModelAdmin class to do so. In consequence, I did add few js lines in openlayers.js to handle the new layer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where we want to change the default map layers used in the admin area. The default `OSMWidget` use the template `django/contrib/gis/templates/gis/openlayers.html`, as its attribute `template_name` is set to `gis/openlayers-osm.html`. It looks like this:

```js
{% extends "gis/openlayers.html" %}
{% load l10n %}

{% block options %}{{ block.super }}
options['default_lon'] = {{ default_lon|unlocalize }};
options['default_lat'] = {{ default_lat|unlocalize }};
options['default_zoom'] = {{ default_zoom|unlocalize }};
{% endblock %}

{% block base_layer %}
var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()});
{% endblock %}
```

We want here to change the `base_layer` variable. Instead of directly modifying this template, override it! Create a template file inside your project's templates directory, say `gis/custom_layers.html` ; and modify `base_layer` with any tiles you want:

```js
{% extends "gis/openlayers-osm.html" %}
{% load l10n %}

{% block base_layer %}
var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: '<a href="https://www.thunderforest.com/">Thunderforest</a>',
        url: "https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<your API key>"
    })
});
{% endblock %}
```

Then in `admin.py` you can subclass `OSMWidget` and specify the custom template. Using `GISModelAdmin` with Django 4.0, `admin.py` may look like this:

```py
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import OSMWidget
from .models import MyModel

class CustomGeoWidget(OSMWidget):
    template_name = 'gis/custom_layers.html'

class CustomGeoModelAdmin(admin.GISModelAdmin):
    gis_widget = CustomGeoWidget
    gis_widget_kwargs = {
        'attrs': {
            'default_zoom': 14,
            'default_lon': 3.4825,
            'default_lat': 50.1906,
        },
    }

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(CustomGeoModelAdmin):
    pass
```